# Another word or words for "purpose driven"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is another word or words for purpose driven?

Answer (score 1):

The first one that comes to mind is "Dedicated."  Especially the 1sd definition according to Merriam-Webster, "[devoted to a cause, ideal, or purpose.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dedicated)"